# Авторизация в React + Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, auth

Всем привет! Я начинаю изучать ReactJS. И в одном из тестовых проектов, столкнулась с проблемой авторизации React + Firebase. Дело в том, что есть 2 компонента: App.js, Auth.js. App собирает в себе другие компоненты, в том числе и Auth. А в то же время компонент Auth выполняет авторизацию через firebase. И я хочу сделать так, чтобы при запуске проекта, у меня первым делом выходила страница авторизации, то есть компонент Auth. И если пользователь прошел авторизацию, то у него открывается доступ к следующим страницам, а если не прошел, то кроме страницы авторизации он никуда не может переходить. Прошу вас объяснить пошагово, потому что я новичок и мало чего пока понимаю( Посоветовали использовать Context или Redux, но я еще их не изучала. Прошу у вас варианты решения в костыльном виде или же с подробным объяснением с использованием Context (немного изучила).

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Auth from './Auth'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/about" render={() => <h1>About page</h1>} />
        <Route exact path="/auth"> 
          <Auth/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/services" render={() => <h1>Services page</h1>} />
        <Route exact path="/contacts" render={() => <h1>Contacts page</h1>} />
        <Route exact path="/">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          </header>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

и компонент Auth.js

```
import React from 'react';
import withFirebaseAuth from 'react-with-firebase-auth'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const firebaseAppAuth = firebaseApp.auth();

const providers = {
  googleProvider: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(),
};


const Auth = (props) =>{
    const {
        user,
        signOut,
        signInWithGoogle,
    } = props;

    return(
        <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
            <h1>Auth page</h1>
            {
            user 
            ? <h1>Hello, {user.displayName}</h1>
            : <h1>Please sign in.</h1>
            }
            {
            user
                ? <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
                : <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default withFirebaseAuth({
    providers,
    firebaseAppAuth,
})(Auth)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот как проходит аторизация в firebase

```
// зарегистрировать пользователя можно так (возвращает promise):
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
// залогиниться пользователь может так (возвращает promise)
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
// ну и подписаться на событие успешной авторизации или потери сессии:
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
     // успешно авторизован, объект user содержит username и т.п.
     this.setState({
         ...this.state,
         user,
     });
  }
});
```

В вашем случае, если не использовать Redux, компонент App, должен хранить состояние юзера. При запуске должна происходить проверка, залогинен ли юзер в данный момент, если да, то никаких изменений, если логина нет, то использовать компонент `<Redirect to={}>` из 'react-router-dom', который перенаправит его в компонент Auth

Comment: a в чем преимущество редиректа перед просто отображением диалога на изначальном роуте?